# Google Chrome input type=“date” mandatory

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, datepicker

Can I make date field in Google Chrome mandatory? In other words I want to remove the cancel ('x') button from the input.

[The input example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnzKf/1/).

```
<input type="date" name="start" id="start" value="2014-02-11">
```

[image]

The current Google Chrome version is 32.0.1700.107 m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `required` to make an input field mandatory

```
<input type="date" name="start" id="start" value="2014-02-11" required />
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/LnzKf/2/

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<input type="date" name="start" id="start" value="2014-02-11" required>
```

link http://jsfiddle.net/LnzKf/3/